# How can I convert number from textbox to int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, struct

can I convert string (numbers) from textbox to int array in struct.

```
OurDataList SingleMemberData = new OurDataList(3);
SingleMemberData = (OurDataList)PlayersData[currentPlayerShown];
**SingleMemberData.champlosses[tabControlChamp.SelectedIndex] = new[] { Convert.ToInt32(mtloss3.Text) };** EDITED
PlayersData[currentPlayerShown] = SingleMemberData;
```

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

I tried to find it, but no answers.

I have also same problem with string in the listbox.

```
SingleMemberData.champ[tabControlChamp.SelectedIndex] = new[] { listBoxChamp.SelectedItem.ToString() };
```

Answer (score 2):

If `SingleMemberData.champwins` is an array, do like this:

```
SingleMemberData.champwins = new[] { Convert.ToInt32(mtwins3.Text) };
```

Comment: @KamilKroko and what? what error do you get? where? what type of properties and variables you have?